# remapping MacBook Power button to work as Esc?

Tags: keyboard

MacBook power button symmetrically mirrors Esc key on MacBook Pro keyboards, so it seems natural to remap make it work as Esc to ease on left-hand some strain, any idea if that's possible?

Comment: You want that only to work in Mathematica, right? Otherwise I would suggest [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). ... Nope. I wouldn't. The On/Off button ist too important. Also I would rather remap it to Del-button.

Comment: Have you already tried fiddling with `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?  I'm on Windows so I am probably not the right person to work on this, but in any case it would probably be useful to know what you have and have not tried.